# Removing UTF-8 from a users inputted string

Tags: python, utf-8

Is there a way to remove a UTF-8 symbol from a string without using any imported methods?

For example:

```
userString = "apples, pears \xc2\xa7 and bananas\ngrapes\nbananas !apples"
```

Desired output:

```
userString = "apples, pears  and bananas\ngrapes\nbananas !apples"
```

Comment: `b'\xc2\xa7'` is `'§'`, which is the section sign, and not and.

Comment: @jsalonen I have tried directly targeting that symbol with userString.replace(" \xc2\xa7", "")

Comment: Did it work or did you get an error?

Comment: @artyer  I'm working on what you said. Is b"\xc2\xa7" a way to directly extract that symbol?

Comment: @jsalonen It didn't work

Comment: Well it works for me. What is your Python version?

Comment: @Enesxg Python strings have no encoding, they are just Unicode. The only way `\xc2\xa7` as one character was if you had a [`bytes`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#binary-sequence-types-bytes-bytearray-memoryview) object, which can be text encoded like that.

Answer (score 0):

Conversion of a `bytes` object using `str` allows you to specify how to handle encoding errors, so you can ignore them like so:

```
>>> userString = b"apples, pears \xc2\xa7 and bananas\ngrapes\nbananas !apples"
>>> str(userString, "ascii", errors="ignore")
'apples, pears  and bananas\ngrapes\nbananas !apples'
```